# jQuery window bind trigger

Tags: jquery, binding

I have this event listener and I'm trying to find out why it gets triggered anytime the URI changes in the browser URL textbox. There is no other reference to this function in the code.The code is from the book Single Page Applications.

```
$(window)
      .bind( 'hashchange', onHashchange )
      .trigger( 'hashchange' );
```

This is all the code:I understand ALL of it except what is in my question. I m sure most of it can be ignored. I just want you to see it in context.

```
spa.shell = (function () {
  //---------------- BEGIN MODULE SCOPE VARIABLES --------------
  var
    configMap = {
      anchor_schema_map : {
        chat  : { open : true, closed : true }
      },
      main_html : String()
        + '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
          + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
          + '<div class="spa-shell-head-acct"></div>'
          + '<div class="spa-shell-head-search"></div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="spa-shell-main">'
          + '<div class="spa-shell-main-nav"></div>'
          + '<div class="spa-shell-main-content"></div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="spa-shell-foot"></div>'
        + '<div class="spa-shell-chat"></div>'
        + '<div class="spa-shell-modal"></div>',
      chat_extend_time     : 1000,
      chat_retract_time    : 300,
      chat_extend_height   : 450,
      chat_retract_height  : 15,
      chat_extended_title  : 'Click to retract',
      chat_retracted_title : 'Click to extend'
    },
    stateMap  = {
      $container        : null,
      anchor_map        : {},
      is_chat_retracted : true
    },
    jqueryMap = {},

    copyAnchorMap,    setJqueryMap,   toggleChat,
    changeAnchorPart, onHashchange,
    onClickChat,      initModule;
  //----------------- END MODULE SCOPE VARIABLES ---------------

  //------------------- BEGIN UTILITY METHODS ------------------
  // Returns copy of stored anchor map; minimizes overhead
  copyAnchorMap = function () {
    return $.extend( true, {}, stateMap.anchor_map );
  };
  //-------------------- END UTILITY METHODS -------------------

  //--------------------- BEGIN DOM METHODS --------------------
  // Begin DOM method /setJqueryMap/
  setJqueryMap = function () {
    var $container = stateMap.$container;

    jqueryMap = {
      $container : $container,
      $chat      : $container.find( '.spa-shell-chat' )
    };
  };
  // End DOM method /setJqueryMap/


  toggleChat = function ( do_extend, callback) {
    var
      px_chat_ht = jqueryMap.$chat.height(),
      is_open    = px_chat_ht === configMap.chat_extend_height,
      is_closed  = px_chat_ht === configMap.chat_retract_height,
      is_sliding = ! is_open && ! is_closed;

    // avoid race condition
    if ( is_sliding ) { return false; }

    // Begin extend chat slider
    if ( do_extend ) {
      jqueryMap.$chat.animate(
        { height : configMap.chat_extend_height },
        configMap.chat_extend_time,
        function () {
          jqueryMap.$chat.attr(
            'title', configMap.chat_extended_title
          );
          stateMap.is_chat_retracted = false;
          if ( callback ) { callback( jqueryMap.$chat ); }
        }
      );
      return true;
    }
    // End extend chat slider

    // Begin retract chat slider
    jqueryMap.$chat.animate(
      { height : configMap.chat_retract_height },
      configMap.chat_retract_time,
      function () {
        jqueryMap.$chat.attr(
         'title', configMap.chat_retracted_title
        );
        stateMap.is_chat_retracted = true;
        if ( callback ) { callback( jqueryMap.$chat ); }
      }
    );
    return true;
    // End retract chat slider
  };

  changeAnchorPart = function ( arg_map ) {
    var
      anchor_map_revise = copyAnchorMap(),
      bool_return       = true,
      key_name, key_name_dep;

    // Begin merge changes into anchor map
    KEYVAL:
    for ( key_name in arg_map ) {
      if ( arg_map.hasOwnProperty( key_name ) ) {

        // skip dependent keys during iteration
        if ( key_name.indexOf( '_' ) === 0 ) { continue KEYVAL; }

        // update independent key value
        anchor_map_revise[key_name] = arg_map[key_name];

        // update matching dependent key
        key_name_dep = '_' + key_name;
        if ( arg_map[key_name_dep] ) {
          anchor_map_revise[key_name_dep] = arg_map[key_name_dep];
        }
        else {
          delete anchor_map_revise[key_name_dep];
          delete anchor_map_revise['_s' + key_name_dep];
        }
      }
    }
    // End merge changes into anchor map

    // Begin attempt to update URI; revert if not successful
    try {
      $.uriAnchor.setAnchor( anchor_map_revise );
    }
    catch ( error ) {
      // replace URI with existing state
      $.uriAnchor.setAnchor( stateMap.anchor_map,null,true );
      bool_return = false;
    }
    // End attempt to update URI...

    return bool_return;
  };
  // End DOM method /changeAnchorPart/
  //--------------------- END DOM METHODS ----------------------

  //------------------- BEGIN EVENT HANDLERS -------------------
  // Begin Event handler /onHashchange/
  // Purpose  : Handles the hashchange event
  // Arguments:
  //   * event - jQuery event object.
  // Settings : none
  // Returns  : false
  // Action   :
  //   * Parses the URI anchor component
  //   * Compares proposed application state with current
  //   * Adjust the application only where proposed state
  //     differs from existing
  //
  onHashchange = function ( event ) {
    var
      anchor_map_previous = copyAnchorMap(),
      anchor_map_proposed,
      _s_chat_previous, _s_chat_proposed,
      s_chat_proposed;

    // attempt to parse anchor
    try { anchor_map_proposed = $.uriAnchor.makeAnchorMap(); }
    catch ( error ) {
      $.uriAnchor.setAnchor( anchor_map_previous, null, true );
      return false;
    }
    stateMap.anchor_map = anchor_map_proposed;

    // convenience vars
    _s_chat_previous = anchor_map_previous._s_chat;
    _s_chat_proposed = anchor_map_proposed._s_chat;

    // Begin adjust chat component if changed
    if ( ! anchor_map_previous
     || _s_chat_previous !== _s_chat_proposed
    ) {
      s_chat_proposed = anchor_map_proposed.chat;
      switch ( s_chat_proposed ) {
        case 'open'   :
          toggleChat( true );
        break;
        case 'closed' :
          toggleChat( false );
        break;
        default  :
          toggleChat( false );
          delete anchor_map_proposed.chat;
          $.uriAnchor.setAnchor( anchor_map_proposed, null, true );
      }
    }
    // End adjust chat component if changed

    return false;
  };
  // End Event handler /onHashchange/

  // Begin Event handler /onClickChat/
  onClickChat = function ( event ) {
    changeAnchorPart({
      chat : ( stateMap.is_chat_retracted ? 'open' : 'closed' )
    });
    return false;
  };
  // End Event handler /onClickChat/
  //-------------------- END EVENT HANDLERS --------------------

  //------------------- BEGIN PUBLIC METHODS -------------------
  // Begin Public method /initModule/
  initModule = function ( $container ) {
    // load HTML and map jQuery collections
    stateMap.$container = $container;
    $container.html( configMap.main_html );
    setJqueryMap();

    // initialize chat slider and bind click handler
    stateMap.is_chat_retracted = true;
    jqueryMap.$chat
      .attr( 'title', configMap.chat_retracted_title )
      .click( onClickChat );

    // configure uriAnchor to use our schema
    $.uriAnchor.configModule({
      schema_map : configMap.anchor_schema_map
    });

    // Handle URI anchor change events.
    // This is done /after/ all feature modules are configured
    // and initialized, otherwise they will not be ready to handle
    // the trigger event, which is used to ensure the anchor
    // is considered on-load
    //
    $(window)
      .bind( 'hashchange', onHashchange )
      .trigger( 'hashchange' );

  };
  // End PUBLIC method /initModule/

  return { initModule : initModule };
  //------------------- END PUBLIC METHODS ---------------------
}());
```

Comment: hashchange is not a cross browser event FYI

Comment: Not sure i understand what you are looking for (or not) but here, each time you reload page, you are triggering onhashchange event. So what is your issue? What do you expect to happen using your code?

Comment: The page is not reloading.

Comment: Anyone? Can I phase it differently so you can understand. What I see is the event handler attached to the window load, but when you click the chat slider, it also fires.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost half way through reading Single Page Web Applications, and I have really learned a lot about how to write clean independent JavaScript modules and how to configure each module.  This book has answered so many design questions that have been spinning in my head.

I believe the answer to your question is on page 123.  The margin note for this block of code is "Update the onClick event handler to make a call to change the URI anchor and then promptly exit, leaving the hashchange event handler in the Shell to pick up the change."

When you click the chat slider, this callback is executed, and then the window's hashchange event automatically executes spa.shell.onHashChange.

```
//------------------- BEGIN EVENT HANDLERS -------------------
onClickToggle = function ( event ){
  var set_chat_anchor = configMap.set_chat_anchor;
  if ( stateMap.position_type === 'opened' ) {
    set_chat_anchor( 'closed' );
  }
  else if ( stateMap.position_type === 'closed' ){
    set_chat_anchor( 'opened' );
  } return false;
};
//-------------------- END EVENT HANDLERS --------------------
```